# switching air valve with Arduino Micro

Tags: arduino, solenoid-valve

Good people of stack. I am a programmer, but new to building my own electronics. I need to switch (3) 12v solenoid valves from the Arduino Micro. I see lots of chatter online, much that confused me greatly.

The valve takes 12v \ 0.3A to close, not sure what inrush there maybe. I don't mind closing on the positive or negative side. Can someone give me a legible sketch of what would be required.

[This](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-4-3-Way-2-Position-Pneumatic-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-DC-12V-NPT/272335306885) is the valve being used.

Comment: You can't drive it directly from the Arduino, you'll need a relay shield, after that it should be pretty simple

Comment: there is a lot of example code and example circuits about how to drive solenoids and dc motors

Answer (score 1):

Use this circuit to control a solenoid valve:
[image]

You can use AO3400A as  N-channel MOSFET, if you are OK with SOT-23 package. Or use IRLZ44N, which is many times more than enough for your load.

Make sure you use flywheel diode D1, it is to protect MOSFET. I think 1N4148 would be enough.

Connect Arduino's ground (negative of voltage source) with the GND shown in circuit.